Without stereographic projection, how does one point compactification of $\mathbb{R}$ look like?
I wanted to ask how does a one point compactification of $\mathbb{R}$ looks like without the use of stereographic projection. 
Clearly the extended real line is not the one point compactification of $\mathbb{R}$ since we add more than one points to the line.
How do I look at it? Is one point compactification of $\mathbb{R}$ is nothing but $(-\infty , \infty]$. Or it's something like equivalence classes where $-\infty $and $\infty$ are in the same class and all other classes are singletons only.
Our professor is using the symbol $\{ \infty\}$ to represent the point at infinity, should it be better to denote it by some other symbol so that such confusion doesn't arise?

It's just the extended real line with  the added relation $+\infty=-\infty.$ So $(-1)^nn$ converges in the one-point compactification to the (single) $\infty,$ while it doesn't converge to anything in the extended real line.

Topologically, the extended real line is a closed interval - it is equivalent to $[-1,1].$ The one-point compactification is equivalent to identifying $1$ and $-1,$ and you get the equivalent of a circle.

The one-point compactification of $\Bbb R$ is not $(-\infty , \infty]$ because the latter (with its topology as a subspace of the extended real line) is not compact. It is (homeomorphic to) the unit circle $S^1$ (to see this, consider some homeomorphism between $\Bbb R$ and $S^1\setminus{\bullet}$ (where $\bullet$ can be any point on $S^1$), and apply the general definition of a one-point-compactification.

@AnneBauval The answer to the linked question uses stereographic projection.

@PaulFrost The linked question itself doesn't, and your answer duplicates it (like my previous comment).

@AmritAwasthi I just realised that the main part of my first comment above, beginning with "It is (homeomorphic to) the unit circle", might be misinterpreted: in this sentence "it" was not denoting the space $(-\infty , \infty]$ but the one-point compactification of $\Bbb R$. So, the comment answered your question. I did not edit it as an anwer because there are already many posts on MSE describing this with more details.

It is common practice to denote the "point at infinity" by $\infty$, but notation is fairly irrelevant.
A one-point compactifiction of a locally compact Hausdorff space $X$ is a compact Hausdorff space $\hat X$ together with an embedding $e_X : X \to \hat X$ such that $R = \hat X \setminus e_X(X)$ is a one-point space. If we want, we can write $R= \{\infty\}$, but as I said above, notation does not play a role.
Certainly your professor proved that one-point compactification is unique in the following sense:
If $(\hat X, e_X)$ and $(\hat Y, e_Y)$ are one-point compactifications of $X$ and $Y$, respectively, and  $h : X \to Y$ is a homeomorphism, then there exists a unique homeomorphism $H : \hat X \to \hat Y$ such that $H \circ e_X = e_Y \circ h$. If not, try to find your own proof. Obviously $H$ is the uniqe function such that $H(\xi) = h(\xi)$ for $\xi \in e_X(X)$ and $H(\infty) = \infty$. Clearly $H$ is a bijection and it suffices to show that it is contiunous (the continuity of $H^{-1}$ follows in the same fashion).
One can of course abstractly define $\bar{\mathbb R} = \mathbb R \cup \{\infty\}$ and introduce a topology by declaring all open subsets $U \subset \mathbb R$ and all complements $\bar{\mathbb R} \setminus C$ of compact subsets $C \subset \mathbb R$ to be open. Then $(\bar{\mathbb R}, i : \mathbb R \hookrightarrow \bar{\mathbb R})$ is the "canonical" one-point compactifiction of $\mathbb R$, but it is perhaps not really illustrative what it looks like.
However, it is easy to see that $\bar{\mathbb R}$ is homeomorphic to the unit circle $S^1 \subset \mathbb R^2$ which gives a nice "geometric model" of the one-point compactification of the real line. To prove it, we must find a homeomorphism between $\mathbb R$ and  $S^1 \setminus \{p\}$, where $p$ is some point of $S^1$. Here are two examples.

Take $p = N  = (0,1) =$  north pole of $S^1$ and  use the sterographic projection $s : S^1 \setminus \{ N\} \to \mathbb R$.

Let $e : (0,1) \to S^1, e(t) = (\cos 2\pi t, \sin 2 \pi t)$. Clearly there exists a homeomorphism $h : \mathbb R \to (0,1)$. Then $\phi = e \circ h : \mathbb R \to S^1$ is an embedding with image $S^1 \setminus \{(1,0)\}$.


